# How come "\n" came into output while geting Input from TextWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
def store():
    add = e3.get("0.1", "end")
    li=[add]
    print(add)
    print(li)



f = Tk()
f.geometry('500x250')


l3 = Label(f, text='Address: ').place(x=10, y=30)
e3 = Text(f, height=2, width=30)
e3.place(x=60, y=30)


b1 = Button(f, text='Submit', command=store).place(x=10, y=170)
f.mainloop()
```

After Entering into TextBox and submitting Im getting \n in output
Here is Output:

> ANYTEXT
>
> ['ANYTEXT\n']
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Suggest me changes so that I don't get output in newline or "\n" in list

Comment: `add = add.rstrip()`

Comment: `0.1` isn't a valid index. The first character of a text widget is `"1.0"`. It works as a side effect of how it's implemented, but you should get in the habit of using proper indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter automatically adds a trailing newline. To get all of the data entered by the user, and *only* the data entered by the user, use `"end-1c"` ("end", minus one character).

```
add = e3.get("1.0", "end-1c")
```

Answer (score 0):

splitting at "\n" will give you all the lines

```
def store():
    add = e3.get("0.1", "end")
    li= add.split("\n")
    print(add)
    print(li)
```

another way would be:

```
a = "Hello World\n"
b = [a[:-1]] #removes last character
print(a) #['Hello World']
```